# Hightlight text inside richtextbox in runtime

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, richtextbox

I need to highlight specific text inside richtext box during runtime, based on a condition. I tried to replace the text with a text with html tags but it didn't render it.

How can I do that?

Comment: based on what condition? please ask in detail in order to avoid a down vote. Please also tell what exactly do u want to do

Comment: thanks. i up voted this question for the sole reason of a prompt acceptance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this . Offcourse, change the code depending on your condition.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (richTextBox1.Text.Contains("red"))
            {
                richTextBox1.SelectionStart = 0;
                richTextBox1.SelectionLength = richTextBox1.Text.Length;
                richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.Black;
                richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.White;
            }
        }
```